# Pasted bulk textual data into a CSV file for text mining in R. But I get a strwidth error saying invalid 'cex' value

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I've copied the text from various emails that I wrote to a friend in order to perform text mining and see how the wordcloud would result in. (packages used are `tm` and `wordcloud`). But when I tried dump the data into a csv file and called the column "letter_text":

`df <- read.csv("Letter_Text.csv")`

`letter_text <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$letter_text))`

I got the following error on running `wordcloud(letter_text)` command on it:

```
Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I thought maybe I'm exceeding the character length of a CSV cell. So, I dumped the data into a text file. `df <- read.table("Letter_Text.txt")`
And I still get the same error.

Something tells me that I'm doing a mistake in creating the dataset for mining the textual data of my emails. How do I resolve this error? Or better is there a particular way to create a dataset for Text Mining with your own data?

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is breaking because you cannot send a corpus to word cloud, only a text vector. Try this with the **quanteda** package: `plot(dfm(corpus(textfile("Letter_Text.cv", textField = "letter_text"))))` and it that works, I will explain why in a detailed answer.

Comment: Turns out you can send a tm Corpus to `wordcloud()`, so the issue must be in the contents of `df$letter_text`, which are apparently empty. Inspect the contents to make sure you are reading in the data that you are expecting.